# \\ for tabularx in macro

Tags: environments, tabularx

I try to define a new environment using tabularx. I understand that tabularx is not a real environment.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{NumBoxes}

 \def \boxy{ 
 & stuff \theNumBoxes & stuff \ifodd\value{NumBoxes}{ \arraybackslash } \fi \stepcounter{NumBoxes}}

\newenvironment{boxes}{
\setcounter{NumBoxes}{0}
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}}
{\endtabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{boxes}
 \boxy \boxy
 \boxy \boxy
\end{boxes}

\end{document}
```

basically I put stuff on second and third column.
Replacing `\arraybackslash` with `\\` does not work either.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I understand that tabularx is not a real environment." And what, in your opinion, is a "real environment"?

Comment: Are you trying to create new lines in the table? Then you should use `\tabularnewline`

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the macro?

Comment: you should use something like `\ifodd\value{NumBoxes} \tabularnewline \fi`, but your column count is wrong. You declare only three columns but use more.

Comment: even without your macro you would get the same error from `{ \\ }` or `{  \arraybackslash }`  you can't end the row inside a group.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite unclear, what you are trying to do. But in your example you do not need `\arraybackslash`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{NumBoxes}

\newcommand*\boxy{% avoid \def in LaTeX
  & stuff \theNumBoxes & stuff \stepcounter{NumBoxes}\tabularnewline
}

\newenvironment{boxes}{%
  \setcounter{NumBoxes}{0}%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}%
}
{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxes}
 \boxy \boxy
 \boxy \boxy
\end{boxes}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image: using \tabularnewline or \\]

Instead of `\tabularnewline` you can also use `\\`, as long as you do not use something like `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` or `\centering` for the last column:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{NumBoxes}

\newcommand*\boxy{% avoid \def in LaTeX
  & stuff \theNumBoxes & stuff \stepcounter{NumBoxes}\\
}

\newenvironment{boxes}{%
  \setcounter{NumBoxes}{0}%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}%
}
{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxes}
 \boxy \boxy
 \boxy \boxy
\end{boxes}

\end{document}
```

For more information about `\arraybackslash` and how to use it, see [the `array` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf). You will find, that `\arraybackslash` is not a replacement of `\\` , but redefines `\\`  to be the "new tabular row" command instead of "new line" command. As already told, this is only needed, if you are using a command, the redefines `\\`  before, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{NumBoxes}

\newcommand*\boxy{% avoid \def in LaTeX
  & stuff \theNumBoxes & stuff \stepcounter{NumBoxes}\\
}

\newenvironment{boxes}{%
  \setcounter{NumBoxes}{0}%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|>{\centering}X|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}%
}
{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxes}
 \boxy \boxy
 \boxy \boxy
\end{boxes}

\end{document}
```

[image: using \centering and \raggedright\arraybackslash]

Comment: `\arraybackslash` isn't doing anything in your 2nd example either, as you are not using `\centering`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right.